# whenever I receive a call a corresponding contact is duplicated, how to fix?

Tags: contacts

whenever I receive a call a corresponding contact is cloned, so I have tons of duplicated similarly named contacts . How to fix?

ZTE Axon 7 mini

Comment: I dont get it. Can you please elaborate? Call from a saved contact or unsaved? Try switching to a different dialing & contacts app. It might be a bug in the sys app itself.